Line does not start with any known Prisma schema keyword error on Python
I'm trying to implement Prisma for a FastAPI project. I added the Prisma package and the schema.prisma file but when I run prisma validate it throws the error:
Environment variables loaded from prisma\.env
Prisma schema loaded from prisma\schema.prisma

Error: Prisma schema validation - (validate wasm)
Error code: P1012
error: Error validating: This line is invalid. It does not start with any known Prisma schema keyword.
  -->  prisma\schema.prisma:1
   | 
   | 
 1 | ﻿datasource db {
 2 |   url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
   | 
error: Error validating: This line is invalid. It does not start with any known Prisma schema keyword.
  -->  prisma\schema.prisma:2
   | 
 1 | ﻿datasource db {
 2 |   url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
 3 |   provider = "postgresql"
   | 
error: Error validating: This line is invalid. It does not start with any known Prisma schema keyword.
  -->  prisma\schema.prisma:3
   | 
 2 |   url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
 3 |   provider = "postgresql"
 4 | }
   | 
error: Error validating: This line is invalid. It does not start with any known Prisma schema keyword.
  -->  prisma\schema.prisma:4
   | 
 3 |   provider = "postgresql"
 4 | }
 5 | 
   | 


But I do not see why. Here is my schema:
datasource db {
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
  provider = "postgresql"
}

generator client {
  provider             = "prisma-client-py"
  recursive_type_depth = 5
}

model User {
  id        Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
  email     String  @unique
  username  String  @db.VarChar(12)
  name      String  @db.VarChar(25)
  lastname  String  @db.VarChar(25)
  password  String  @db.VarChar(20)
}

I'm starting to learn prisma so I dont' know if I'm doing something wrong.

First thought: Could it be that your file has an UTF-8 BOM that isn't being handled properly when prisma loads the file?

Yeees, I just tried it and that was indeed the case! Thank you!! :))

As @MatsLindh said in the comments, the problem was due to the UTF-8 BOM and was solved by simply removing it.

